# SQL Server : can disabling a trigger delete it?

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Server maintenance plan that is run every night. For it to run correctly, I need to disable a trigger and then I enable it after the query runs. At some point, the trigger was deleted and I need to make sure that the below code did not delete it.

```
EXEC('DISABLE TRIGGER UPT ON ContactsQPROFILE');

UPDATE ContactsQPROFILE
SET QTOTALNETWORTH = QVALUEOFHOME
FROM ContactsQPROFILE 
WHERE (QVALUEOFHOME > QTOTALNETWORTH)
  AND (QVALUEOFHOME > 0.00);

EXEC('ENABLE TRIGGER UPT ON ContactsQPROFILE');
```

I am hoping that someone can confirm that the above code did not delete the query.

Comment: Disabling a trigger is not the same thing as dropping a trigger. The code you posted will NOT drop a trigger. But how do you know the trigger was dropped?

Comment: The trigger is not there anymore.

Comment: What is the result of this? select * from sys.triggers where name = 'UPT'

Comment: You don't need to use dynamic sql to disable and enable triggers. Also, a more descriptive name than UPT would be a good idea.

Comment: The naming of the triggers is out of my control.  It was done by the writers of a program we use.    When I ran the SELECT query above it returned nothing.

Comment: Then the trigger has been dropped. The code you posted will not ever drop that trigger, it only disables and enables it. Something else dropped it.

Answer (score 0):

use the following commands instead:

```
ALTER TABLE ContactsQPROFILE DISABLE TRIGGER UPT 
GO
    UPDATE ContactsQPROFILE
SET QTOTALNETWORTH = QVALUEOFHOME
FROM ContactsQPROFILE 
WHERE (QVALUEOFHOME > QTOTALNETWORTH)
  AND (QVALUEOFHOME > 0.00);
GO
ALTER TABLE ContactsQPROFILE ENABLE TRIGGER UPT
```